# How to transition to a new view in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, uialertview, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

My goal is to have the user click a button that then gives them a choice of yes or cancel, this works fine.  Is yes is selected it should move to the Camera View. I am getting the error: Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var showAlert = false

 var body: some View {
        NavigationStack
        {
                VStack {
                        
                    Button{
                        showAlert = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .symbolVariant(.fill)
                        .background(.red)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.trailing,300)
                    Spacer() 
            }
            .alert("Create Event Here?", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Button("Yes"){NavigationLink("addCameraView", destination: CameraView())//*****gets the error
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
                }
        }
```

```
struct CameraView: View{
    
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var imagePickerDisplay = false

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if selectedImage != nil {
                    Image(uiImage: selectedImage!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "snow")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                }
                Button("Camera") {
                    self.sourceType = .camera
                    self.imagePickerDisplay.toggle()
                }.padding()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Take a Photo of the Event")
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$imagePickerDisplay) {
                ImagePickerView(selectedImage: self.$selectedImage, sourceType: self.sourceType)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't put a `NavigationLink` with a destination inside an alert: the `NavigationStack` is in the view, you can't navigate inside an alert. You could use a navigation path to got to another view programmatically. On a side note, the `NavigationView` inside the `CameraView` looks completely useless.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, even if I move the navigation link to its own button the same error occurs

Comment: `NavigationLink` is not an action, it's a view: you can't use it inside the action closure of a `Button`. You can use a button to change a variable, such as the navigation path. Use `NavigationLink` as any other element inside the `View` - take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate with a button, we need to utilize a variable as our trigger. Wrapping the button in a `NavigationLink` and updating the associated variable to the appropriate value will trigger the navigation.

Below you will find the updated `ContentView`. `CameraView` remains unchanged.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack
        {
            
            VStack {
                
                Button{
                    showAlert = true
                } label: {
                    Text("+")
                }
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .symbolVariant(.fill)
                .background(.red)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.trailing,300)
                Spacer()
            }
            .alert("Create Event Here?", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                NavigationLink(destination: CameraView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button("Yes"){
                        selection = 1
                    }
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                    selection = nil
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```